# How to check if sidebar is open in Android?

Tags: android, sidebar

I have an app which uses a sidebar. A button opens and closes that sidebar. I need to know when the sidebar is open, so that then the button can close it and vice versa. So how to check if the sidebar is open or closed?

*Note: The sidebar's code is in a .jar file, so I cannot modify it. I can just modify the button and the app.

Comment: when first time app loads is it the side bar already open first time?

Comment: @BhavikKama No, it is closed.

Comment: then just take simple boolean variable..and u know first time its closed..then whenever the button close or open u can change that bool variable value accordingly..as u said your sidebar code is in .jar..so you can do this only with your button

Comment: @BhavikKama I tried that, but the sidebar also closes when the user clicks back. So a boolean flag won't work..

Comment: then in that case you have to put all those bool condition in each scenario..as you said you don't have access to side bar code..so thats the only way

Comment: @BhavikKama OK, but there must be a more elegant solution?

Comment: but if u dont have access to your sidebar then may be it difficult..let me give you one logical answer.i am not that aware of android but in ios if this was the scenario i have some methods that tell me that which view is on top.so in case of sidebar is open my view is at back so i can know that side bar is open else sidebar is closed .so if you can google with this concept you will surely find something.best luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

set a `Boolean` flag when you press the button. check this flag to know the state of sidebar.

initialize flag as false. and on button click change the state of flag.

Comment: That won't work, as when the user swipes or clicks the back button, the sidebar closes. So in those cases the flag would be set to the wrong value.

Comment: change the flag OnBackPress and swipe.